# What does ":before :after :around" really mean in defmethod?

Tags: common-lisp

In the following code, can i remove the ":after" ?

(defmethod render-page-body :after ((app weblocks-webapp) rendered-html)
;...)

I am really new for CLOS, so sorry for my newbie question ?

Comment: See http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/object-reorientation-generic-functions.html and http://psg.com/~dlamkins/sl/chapter14.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `:after` means that the code in the body of the method is executed after the primary method, rather than being the primary method.

Similarly `:around` means that the body "replaces" the primary function, with it still being available. This allows you to perform some class-specific things before the primary method is called, then perform some other things after the primary method has been called.